# Rails webpacker in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

Bit of a strange scenario but let me explain. I have a view that needs to output a number of cars.  The car photos are stored on Amazon S3.  Some cars have photos whereas others do not. The ones that don't, need their image to display a locally stored placeholder graphic.  The Car model has a boolean field to denote whether there is a photo for the car or not.

The part of the car partial is as follows:

```
<div class="car__photo-inner">
    <img src="<%= car.photo_or_placeholder_url({size: :thumb, aspect: :square}) %>" />
</div>
```

The method in my Car model is as such:

```
def photo_or_placeholder_url(options = {})
  if photo
    photo_url(options)
  else
    asset_pack_path File.join(["media", "images", "placeholder.jpg"])
  end
end
```

`photo_url` just uses the options to grab the correct URL from Amazon S3 and works perfectly.

Where I am struggling is with getting the placeholder image to display.  The placeholder is stored in /app/javascript/images.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks,
Neil

Comment: Are you using a library to upload images to S3? Like Carrierwave?

Comment: Did you import the image in Webpack?

Comment: @cannon-moyer No, no library used for this. I’m manually uploading them. There will be a finite number and it’s only me uploading them.

Comment: @rossta    Yes I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions?

**Yes.** Don't do it in the model. Models in Rails are already insanely overtaxed with responsibilities. And this is actually purely a view concern. Models really should only be concerned with the business logic and not the presentation if possible.

#### So where then?

A helper method or a [decorator](https://github.com/infinum/rails-handbook/blob/master/Design%20Patterns/Decorators.md):

```
module CarsHelper
  def car_photo(car, **options)
    url = if car.photo 
      car.photo_url(options)
    else
      "placeholder.jpg"
    end
    image_tag(url)
  end
end
```

---

```
<div class="car__photo-inner">
  <%= car_photo(car) %>
</div>
```

If the placeholder image is a developer concern just place it in `app/assets/images` and use the conventions instead of fighting them.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much. Code ended up like:

    `def car_photo_or_placeholder(car, **options)
        url = if car.photo 
            car.photo_url(options)
        else
            asset_pack_path "media/images/placeholder.jpg"
        end

        url
    end`